# best ubuntu samba guide

Tags: 12.04, server, filesystem, samba

after trying the official Ubuntu samba guide and failing, then a youtube video guide and failing to make samba work, I am asking all of you which one is best as there are so many to choose from.

I tried ftp and nfs after these and got both to work, but found out ftp wasn't exactly a live system and windows 7 pro can't connect to nfs, so I have a good general feeling for configuration in general

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Samba is an implementation of the Server Message Block (SMB)/Common Internet File System (CIFS) protocol for Unix systems, providing support for cross-platform file and printer sharing with Microsoft Windows, OS X, and other Unix systems.

[The Official Samba-3 HOWTO and Reference Guide](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba3-HOWTO.pdf)

[Samba-3 by Example](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/Samba3-ByExample.pdf)

[Install Samba Server on Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/install-samba-server-on-ubuntu/)

[Install and Configure Samba Server](http://ubuntuserverguide.com/2012/06/install-samba-server-ubuntu-server-1204-lts.html)

[Setting Up A Linux File Server Using Samba](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-linux-file-server-using-samba)

[Configure Samba Sharing between Ubuntu and Windows](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/03/configure-samba-sharing-between-ubuntu.html)

I hope these help.

Comment: Thanks, the 4th link helped me get it working, for future reference.

Comment: Glad that I could help :)